# Why was the number $\pi$ unique for n-sphere?

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics

The following question might contain more philosophical than [actual calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Closed_forms).

From $S^0$ the $0$-sphere, which was two dots on a line, to a $1$-sphere, which was a connected circle in a plane, [$\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) emerged, and it was used thereafter for $n$-sphere recursion and all the nice function such as Fourier exponential, etc.

However, it suddenly bothered me a bit to see that the value of $\pi$ was unique, that upon rising from $S^0$ to $S^1$ it emerged, and that a single structure constant $\pi$ was used for whatever there was after. Couldn't there be a new $\pi_i$?

In some sense that it was true, since $\pi^2$ was evidently a completely different number than $\pi$ as the digit never repeat itself. But, still, why there wasn't additional new structure constant like $pi$ emerge from the transition of $S^1$ to $S^2$?

What's more interesting was the following observation. From $n=1$ to $n=2$, $\pi$ emerged, the continuous was where the physics changed, as nowadays it required complex domain. The single $\pi$ thus carried on until $n=3$. However, from $n=3$ to $n=4$, $\pi^2$ emerged, it's also where physics changed completely, as four vectors and spacetime conservation came in. Notice that the discussion to continue the current physics to $n=5$ was [somewhat seriously discussed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-dimensional_space). Correspondingly, the new appearance of $\pi^3$ happened at $n=6$, the dimension where [several notice of the string theory came into play(except the non-gravity ones)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six-dimensional_space#String_theory). At first occurrence of $\pi^4$, i.e. $n=8$, lots of existing geometry understanding broke if recall it correctly.

It seemed as if, at each appearance of a new order of $\pi$, serious geometry and physical implication came into play, where, in fact, changed the understanding completely. I'd like to know if there's any thoughts regard to this relationship, or if it was just a coincidence.

Back to the original question, wasn't it so troubling that the $\pi$ was unique? Could there be new complementary constants appear in transition between $S^1$ to $S^2$, just like the appearance of prime number in integers, i.e. $\pi_1=\pi$, and what about $\pi_2$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "$\pi$ emerged from the transition from $S^0$ to $S^1$". Sole fact that $S^0$ is discrete (and finite) while no other $S^n$ is already shows that $S^0$ is a special case. Either way, this is a philosophical question. It's like asking "why the world is as it is". I don't think this is the right place to ask such questions.

Comment: IMO, the link you provide precisely answers your question: $\pi$ appears as a factor in the recurrence relation on $n$. So whatever $\pi$ is, its powers will appear in the expressions of the volumes. Review the "Recurrences" section, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Recurrences.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, the calculus was in there I'm not question that. However, naively speaking without knowing the proof, but only the "experimental" observation, in the sense that one can pour the water out of a sphere and measure it, suppose that $\pi_0=0$(at $\emptyset$), $\pi_1=1$(at $S^0$), and $\pi_2=\pi$(at $S^1$), since the recurrence was $2$ and that accounted for "even" number, and $0$ and $1$ was added for the closure. Wasn't it nature to ask for a $\pi_3$?i.e. some other "odd" $\pi_i$?

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate: "experimentally", you cannot "discover" any $\pi$. The volumes of the hyperspheres are found by integration, which leads to the recurrence relation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust (That's completely not the point but just to answer the question) Use a compass and draw a circle on a metal plate and cut it. From the disk make a cylinder of 1 meter high. Pour in the water to fill the cylinder container. Measure the mass as precisely as you could or pour out the water to a cubic, either, the relation was recovered and you can extract $\pi$, with CLT if necessary. Measurement could be done explicitly, regardless the calculation. Some care might be needed in $n=4$, and the experiments stopped.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate: as is well known, $\pi_4$ and $\pi_5$ differ in the fifteenth decimal.